# Continuous unanswered questions

Tags: discussion, support, answers, unanswered-questions

I have posted several questions on SO, and only ONE of them has received a response, not necessarily an answer.

Due to this, I must ask:

Are there things that I can do to make my questions more "seen"? Seems as if there are new questions posted nearly every second.

Does reputation points play a role into it or something?

Does anyone else have any good reliable resources for getting answers (hate to say it, but maybe other sites)?

Comment: Keep editing and improving your question.  Take heed of any comments asking for clarifications.

Comment: @PolyGeo I get nothing. Not even comments.

Comment: I just looked quickly at the four questions that you have asked at [so] and it seems to me that you are asking for ideas (one even says brainstorming) rather than asking a focussed question.  When I look for questions to answer I look for those which say clearly what they have tried and where they are stuck.  To me this is your question least likely to attract potential answerers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35977336/server-2008-r2-task-manager-tsadmin-remote-control-session-via-a-coding-method - I'm surprised it has not been closed as Too Broad.

Comment: @Gerneio - There are three primary reasons a question does not receive an answer.  1) The question is not clear, if you get comments asking for clarification, that is a clue your question is not clear to other people.  2) The question might have quality problems, people who don't research a topic, often end up asking poor quality questions.  A question can be poor quality if you are asking how to mitigate behavior instead of solving the problem.  3) The question is of high quality and is clear yet the person who knows the answer has not seen the question.

Comment: 4). The person who will know the answer isn't even born yet (and probably never will). This applies to most of the SharePoint related questions.